# How to open a file in an active workbook? VB.NET 2008

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a program that filters data and then outputs it to a tabg delimited file. I then use Excel Interop to open this file in Excel because directly outputting to a worksheet takes too long. So currently I am using this code:

```
    AD.DF.WriteToFile(vbTab)
    Dim WB As Workbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(AD.DF.DatafileInfo.WriteToFileLocation)
    ExcelApp.Visible = True
```

The first line takes the filtered data and outputs to a tab delimited file. The second opens that same file in a new workbook in Excel. And obviously the third makes Excel visible. Here is my problem though: right now when this code is run there are **two** open workbooks. I already have an active workbook and I would just like to open this file to that workbook.

If this is possible, how do I do it? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code I created an object that is an Excel Workbook. I then set the created workbook as the ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook. Then I was able to open the file without another workbook being created.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [GetObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9waz863%28VS.71%29.aspx) function.

```
Dim MyXL As Object
MyXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
```

should get you a reference to the currently running instance of Excel.